# How to change/forward IP:Port mapping

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, netstat

I have a application that binds to `127.0.0.1:9000`. I can't access from other nodes on the network due to this. I want it to appear as my-machine-name:9000 instead.

How can I do this in Ubuntu. Iptables / forwarding maybe?

Comment: Can you tell us what application? There may be settings to change the IP address to something else like you private network (i.e. 192.168.0.0). `iptables` is used to forward packets from one machine to another, not to redirect a local server LISTEN to the world.

Comment: Thanks, its Hadoop, HDFS. I already set the following in core-site.xml file:
`<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>my-machine-name:9000/</value>
 </property>`

Comment: If my-machine-name resolves to 127.0.0.1 then you need to use a different name or directly an IP address.

Comment: Used both `my-machine-name` and `IP` address in `core-site.xml`. Both show `127.0.0.1:9000` when run `netstat -pln`. Still not able to connect from another node. That was why I wanted to try IP tables as a fix, maybe?

Comment: You need to use your private network IP address. You should see it when you do `ifconfig`. Usually the first entry, it has been called `eth0`, although now a day, that changes so much... That's the IP address you need to use.

Comment: Yes, I use that. But when a worker tries to connect during a job running, there is an error `connection refused`. Seems the node needs to listen on public address 0.0.0.0 or something like that.

Comment: Yes. The problem with 0.0.0.0 is that it is then open to anyone who can connect to that server. If it's local to your organization (no Internet access or behind a firewall) then you should be fine.